# Issue with zeroBasedEnums option in OpenAPI Generator

Tags: openapi-generator

I am currently working with OpenAPI Generator to generate a C# SDK for my API. I'm facing an issue with the zeroBasedEnums option. According to the documentation, setting this option to true should make enums start with 0, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here's the relevant part of my configuration file:

```
{
    "zeroBasedEnums": true
}
```

Despite setting zeroBasedEnums to true, the generated enums still start with 1. I have searched through the documentation and forums, but I couldn't find a solution. Is there something I might be missing or is this a known issue with OpenAPI Generator?